# Creating an OLAP data warehouse from an OLTP AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, postgresql, amazon-rds, data-warehouse

I have an OLTP AWS RDS(in postgresql and very normalized) that powers an application. I am trying to create a separate data warehouse(OLAP use case) also in AWS RDS(postgresql) using a star shchema. I am not considering redshift as it is more expensive and the amount of data does not warrant it. As an AWS newbie, my question is are there certain tool within the AWS stack that will allow me to build a data warehouse type RDS based of off an OLTP RDS? Any suggestions regarding data copying/data syncing between two RDSs etc. is of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Data Migration Service](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/). I'm not saying it is what you need, but it might help. You're probably going to have to roll your own.

Comment: Thank you. I will research this tool.